# Search for specific column header names, copy columns and paste to append to another wookbooksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

My workbook has one,two or three sheets. 
Each sheet can contain at least one of these column header names: "Tel" or "Number".

How can I copy the entire columns ( data only)  with these column header names 
and paste them (as an append in just one column with the same column header name) into another workbook sheet where the VBA code ( Sheet Module) is. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Option Compare Text

Sub search_and_append()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim width As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim telList As Object
    Dim count As Long
    Dim numList As Object
    Set telList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set numList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    ' search for all tel/number list on other sheets
    ' Assuming header means Row 1
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> Me.Name Then
            With ws
                .Activate
                width = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                For i = 1 To width
                    If Trim(.Cells(1, i).Value) = "Tel" Then
                        Height = .Cells(.Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Row
                        If Height > 1 Then
                            For j = 2 To Height
                                If Not telList.exists(.Cells(j, i).Value) Then
                                    telList.Add .Cells(j, i).Value, ""
                                End If
                            Next j
                        End If
                    End If
                    If Trim(.Cells(1, i).Value) = "Number" Then
                        Height = .Cells(.Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Row
                        If Height > 1 Then
                            For j = 2 To Height
                                If Not numList.exists(.Cells(j, i).Value) Then
                                    numList.Add .Cells(j, i).Value, ""
                                End If
                            Next j
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End With
        End If

    Next

    ' paste the tel/number list found back to this sheet
    With Me
        .Activate
        width = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To width
            If Trim(.Cells(1, i).Value) = "Tel" Then
                Height = .Cells(.Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Row
                count = 0
                For Each tel In telList
                    count = count + 1
                    .Cells(Height + count, i).Value = tel
                Next
            End If
            If Trim(.Cells(1, i).Value) = "Number" Then
                Height = .Cells(.Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Row
                count = 0
                For Each tel In telList
                    count = count + 1
                    .Cells(Height + count, i).Value = tel
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, @Larry and kimtch, but doesn't work. Errors appear in Me. Name and With Me. I replaced this Name Me, create one Sheet with Me name in import workbook, changed ws set, etc, etc. I will appreciate if you fix this erros. Thank you.

Comment: @user2127061  Put the code in the sheet module, e.g. target sheet is sheet 1, then put the code insde sheet 1's code module.

Comment: Hi,@Larry. Now it Works. The problem was the place where I put the code. Although column Header Names "Number" aren't caught. Then I replace "Number" by "TEL".Could you adapt this?

Comment: @user2127061 can you clarify the problem?  Do you mean that you want to put all data found in "number" or "tel" and append to the same columN? And if this code solves your original problem, you may want to accept it.

Comment: Hi, @Larry. Testing the code, it get "TEL" colunm in sheet 1 but doesn't "NUMBER" column in sheet 2 to put all data in just one column, in my case, colunm A, sheet "Tratamento", in Workbook 2. But what you do already help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, in the target worksheet, you want all matched column "TEL" or "NUMBER" to output to the same list on the target worksheet with column number "TEL"?

Comment: Hi, @Larry. Exactly. I used Replace Method to convert all "Number" columns to "Tel" and Works well.