# Search for specific column header, copy column and paste to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, header, copy-paste

How can I copy the columns (data only) with these column header names "TOOL CUTTER" and "HOLDER" and paste them (as an append in just one column each with the same column header name) into another workbook sheet where the VBA code ( Sheet Module) is. Thanks.

The line `"If Sht <> "masterfile.xls" Then` is where the problem occurs. I got help from another online source where this line was `If ws.name <> me.name Then` clearly I was meant to put a different name here but I cannot figure out what.

**Does not need to be this method of solving, this is just what I currently have.**

I am opening multiple files which is why I mostly use ActiveSheet methods not Sheet1 Sheet2. The file that my code is in is called "masterfile.xls"

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Previous code outline help found here: [Search for specific column header names, copy columns and paste to append to another wookbooksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538847/search-for-specific-column-header-names-copy-columns-and-paste-to-append-to-ano)

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer

    'Speed up process by not updating the screen
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

Set Sht = ActiveSheet

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 1
    'loop through directory file and print names
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) <> "xls" And LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) <> "xls" Then
        Else
            'print file name
            Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
            i = i + 1
            Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name

        End If

        Dim k As Long
        Dim width As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim TOOLList As Object
        Dim count As Long
        Set TOOLList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        ' search for all tel/number list on other sheets
        ' Assuming header means Row 1
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If Sht <> "masterfile.xls" Then
                With ActiveSheet
                    .Activate
                    width = .Cells(10, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    For k = 1 To width
                        If Trim(.Cells(10, k).Value) = "CUTTING TOOL" Then
                            Height = .Cells(.Rows.count, k).End(xlUp).Row
                            If Height > 1 Then
                                For j = 2 To Height
                                    If Not TOOLList.exists(.Cells(j, k).Value) Then
                                        TOOLList.Add .Cells(j, k).Value, ""
                                    End If
                                Next j
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End With
            End If

        Next

        ' paste the TOOL list found back to this sheet
        With masterfile.xls
            .Activate
            width = .Cells(10, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For k = 1 To width
                If Trim(.Cells(10, k).Value) = "CUTTING TOOL" Then
                    Height = .Cells(.Rows.count, k).End(xlUp).Row
                    count = 0
                    For Each TOOL In TOOLList
                        count = count + 1
                        .Cells(Height + count, k).Value = TOOL
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End With








        'Range("J1").Select
        'Selection.Copy
        'Windows("masterfile.xlsm").Activate
        'Range("D2").Select
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next objFile

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sht` is a reference to a worksheet object. You're comparing it to a string which looks like the name of a workbook. Presumably you're trying to check if the active sheet has a specific name in which case you could use  `If Sht.Name <> "Some Name" Then`. Alternatively, if you're trying to check whether Sht is not part of the workbook "masterfile.xls" then you could use `If Sht.Parent.Name <> "masterfile" Then`.

Answer (score 6):

- `sht` refers to the active worksheet in the workbook in which this code resides, because `Set Sht = ActiveSheet`
- `sht` is an object variable, and will never be equal to the string value `"masterfile.xls"`
- `sht.name` will give you the (string) name of the worksheet which you could compare to the string value `"masterfile.xls"`, but that still won't tell you what you're after because:

  - You're confusing the name of the `WorkSheet` (`sht.name`) with the file name of the `WorkBook` (`masterfile.xls`).
- `If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) <> "xls" And Case(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) <> "xls" Then Else` is a very awkward construct. Change that to:

  - `If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" or Case(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then` and eliminate the `else` clause. it will make it much more readable
- I presume that `If Sht <> "masterfile.xls" Then` is intended to skip the processing of the WorkBook `masterfile.xls` if that's the case then:

  - `If Sht.Cells(i, 1) <> "masterfile.xls" Then` should do the trick, since you stored the file name earlier in  your code. (Note: you immediately increment `i` after using it, so you have to use one smaller value here.)
- `Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name` will open the new workbook, but makes it too easy to get confused on which workbook you're looking at. Try `Set NewWb = Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name`, now you have a firm handle with which to reference this one.
- `With ActiveSheet
                  .Activate` is simply redundant. `ActiveSheet` is the *active* sheet, there's no need to activate it.
- `With masterfile.xls` is a totally non-functional statement. `With` is expecting some sort of collection object to work with, which `masterfile.xls` is not. It's not a string (no quotes), it's not a variable of any sort (never declared), it's not an object (masterfile) with a method or property (xls). This indicates that you don't have `Option Explicit` set at the top of your code. You should always do this, as it will make this a compile-time error instead of a run-time error.
- If the above *had* worked, `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` would have closed the workbook you're running from, because you would have activated it.

Try this code, it's probably not 100%, it should at least get you closer to what you're after:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer

    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    Set StartSht = ActiveSheet

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2
    'loop through directory file and print names
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
            'print file name
            StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
            Dim NewWb As Workbook
            Set NewWb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name)
        End If

        Dim k As Long
        Dim width As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim TOOLList As Object
        Dim count As Long
        Set TOOLList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        ' search for all tel/number list on other sheets
        ' Assuming header means Row 1
        If objFile.Name <> "masterfile.xls" Then 'skip any processing on "Masterfile.xls"
            For Each ws In NewWb.Worksheets   'assuming we want to look through the new workbook
                With ws
                    width = .Cells(10, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    For k = 1 To width
                        If Trim(.Cells(10, k).Value) = "CUTTING TOOL" Then
                            Height = .Cells(.Rows.count, k).End(xlUp).Row
                            If Height > 1 Then
                                For j = 2 To Height
                                    If Not TOOLList.exists(.Cells(j, k).Value) Then
                                        TOOLList.Add .Cells(j, k).Value, ""
                                    End If
                                Next j
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End With
            Next
        End If

        ' paste the TOOL list found back to this sheet
        With StartSheet
            width = .Cells(10, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For k = 1 To width
                If Trim(.Cells(10, k).Value) = "CUTTING TOOL" Then
                    Height = .Cells(.Rows.count, k).End(xlUp).Row
                    count = 0
                    For Each TOOL In TOOLList
                        count = count + 1
                        .Cells(Height + count, k).Value = TOOL
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End With
        NewWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        i = i + 1
    Next objFile

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand and explaining so much. This is wonderful. What I'm trying to do is open the NewWb, copy the items in column J (preferably written as column 10) under the header "CUTTING TOOL" until the list is empty, and paste that into the Masterfile in column 3 also titled "CUTTING TOOL" of the same row the file name is printedto in the first column.

When I try your code, I get an error at the line 'paste the TOOL list...
width = .Cells(10, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
that says Error: object required. I checked and width is properly defined...any thoughts?

Comment: This error is the last block toward the bottom @FreeMan

Comment: Exactly as that's typed (Including the `Option Explicit` at the very top), I get a compile time error indicating `Variable not defined` and pointing at `With StartSheet`. Looking at it, that's the case, the variable is `StartSht`. When I fixed that, the next line: `width = .Cells(10, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column`, executed just fine in my very minimal test case. Chasing after the definition of `width` is a red-herring - it's not an object, and `.Column` doesn't return an object. If you re-typed the code, there may be a typo, if the `StartSheet` -> `StartSht` change doesn't fix it.

Comment: Yes, that helped to fix that line. I copy/pasted your work to see if I made a type when re-typing mine, fixed the StartSht line, but I get back "error: variable not defined" on a new section of the code, the section starting with  `If objFile.Name <> "masterfile.xls" Then` in the line `Height = .Cells(.Rows.count, k).End(xlUp).Row` highlighting the word Height. I realize I have k defined but not j. Would that Fix be Dim j As ... Height?

Comment: In that line of code, `j` (which is poorly named) represents the row that you're looking at. If you rename `j` to something more meaningful like `ToolRow`, then A) it's easier to understand your code, and B) it's easy to figure out what data type it needs to be - there is no data type `Height`, but there is `Integer` (holds a value up to 32,767) and `Long` (hold a value up to 2,147,483,647). If you're _sure_ you'll never have more than 32,767 rows of data to deal with, `Dim ToolRow as Integer`, but `Dim ToolRow as Long` just to be safe.

Comment: As a side note, most of your loop variables are poorly named as their names don't describe the information they hold. For loop counters, it's easy to fall into this trap (I do it a lot), but it does make your code more readable, and makes things like your question a lot easier to answer on your own, just by thinking about what this variable needs to do.

Comment: Ah thank you for explaining! I don't have a lot of experience with VBA so most of my code is pieced together and I'm not always sure what all of it represents so I get nervous trying to alter it if I'm not confident in what it is. Do you have any other suggestions of things I should rename?
Also, do you know why it still kicks back the error that `Height =` comes back as the error: variable is not defined?

Comment: Ah yes. It says in the line `For each Tool in TOOLList` that tool is not defined. Would I define that as an object?

Comment: The accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296522/looping-through-a-scripting-dictionary-using-index-item-number) question should help you with the structure for reading back from your dictionary.